# Android GridLayout. How to get views surrounding a clicked view?

Tags: android, grid-layout

Android beginner. Not native English speaker so forgive me for any mistakes.

In a GridLayout(4,4) I have 15 buttons labeled 1..15 and the last is white. Buttons have a onClickListener set.

```
1  2  3  4  
5  6  7  8  
9  10 11 12  
13 14 15 (W)hite
```

Now, if the user click on 15 the clicked button should swap its position with the white button.

```
1  2  3  4  
5  6  7  8  
9  10 11 12  
13 14 (W) 15
```

Now, and for the duration of the game the user can click only buttons above, below, to the left or to the right of the white one. If white one i sclicked nothing happen.
What I did:

- Setup a gridlayout xml file without children as I add them
  programatically;
- Save a "pointer" to the white button so I have a valid reference to it for removing and readding it.

What I can't do:
Once removed both the clicked button and the white button I can't re-adding them in the reverse position. I have X,Y of each button but in the several addView() methods there's no parameters about positioning in the layout on X,Y values base. I guess the addView() methods with LayoutParams could be right but I really don't understand how to use LayoutParams to get the View's position (coordinates) inside the gridLayout.
Hope I was clear enough.
Thanks in advance to all contributors.
As I said, I'm a beginner so if my approach isn't correct I'm opened to a completely different solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good example of using GridView with custom adapter: http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-gridview-example/

You can use integer array instead of String array. In this array you must save id of all views which can be used in GridView. In getView you just implement this layout by id from array. Also you set OnClickListner to this View and when you click on someone you just change "white View" instead of "View with number" id in integer array.

Then call notifyDataSetChanged. 
Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thank you QArea. I have to admit knowing very little (almost nothing) about Adapters use. I know what Adapters are a why use them but I actually never work on them. The link you provided has unfortunately no simple, written explanation beyond the code so I'm still stuck. It's an occasion to study Adapters. Thanks again.

Comment: @byMurru Here is a good tutorial how to use adapters: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: Yeah I,m reading those both. I guess I made a wrong choice at the beginning. My 16 button/views are fixed. I use a gridLAyout because don't know much yet about Android. The layout is like a board and the buttons are the pawns. I need just to move them. But using removeView reduce the index in getChildCount() so when I re-add the views I get an OutOfIndexException. Working on it.